# is htdocs a good place to put my very protected scripts in?

Tags: php, xampp

I am doing some rearrangements with my files, and I have a folder called `PScripts` that is reserved for system calls that I call upon to process internal server actions.
I need that folder to be out of reach of the sophisticated user and there should be no access to it. only for the system itself.

So, putting the folder inside `htdocs` should be ok, or should it be put somewhere else ?

Comment: No, it should be put outside htdocs then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place it outside the document root.

When it's placed inside `htdocs`, its access can be restricted via `.htaccess`. However, this does not protect the files from being a victim of typos of the site maintainer.

I have seen a case where PHP files (including hard-coded passwords) were exposed to the public, due to a crash or misconfiguration of the server.

Comment: Absolutely correct, if the PHP engine crashes for whatever reason, you don't want usernames and passwords exposed.